# Automating file processing in bash with sequential numbering

Tags: bash, scripting

I have binary files in a directory containing timespec time stamps in following format:

```
timeStamps_from_callId_1
timeStamps_from_callId_2
timeStamps_from_callId_3
timeStamps_from_callId_4
timeStamps_from_callId_5
......
```

and I have a program called `timing_reader` in the same directory which has following format:

```
Usage: ./timing_reader <timing-file> [output file]
```

Now I want to automate the processing of these files through Bash scripting in such a way that each output file will be named as exactly the input file with .csv extension. For example:

```
./timing_reader timeStamps_from_callId_1 timeStamps_from_callId_1.csv
```

and

```
./timing_reader timeStamps_from_callId_2 timeStamps_from_callId_2.csv
```

and so on. I am a very basic user of Bash and have no experience of scripting whatsoever. Any sort of help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, for loop?:

```
for i in timeStamps_from_callId_*;
do
   ./timing_reader ${i} ${i}.csv
done
```

Or, awk?:

```
ls timeStamps_from_callId_* | awk '{printf "./timing_reader %s %s.csv",$0,$0}' | sh -
```

Comment: The for loop did the job although I had to include a sleep statement to let the processing of first file finish before starting the next one. Thanks for the help.